# Main~.storyboard file ,which is like a side effect

Tags: ios, xcode, file, storyboard

I use multiple storyboards in my personal project. And I noticed there existed *~.storyboard like Main~.storyboard .

I don't know that is why, which is like a side effect. Although my project is quite OK, I'd like to get some explanations.

#### Here is the Xcode outline.

> [image]

#### Here is the folder of the project

> [image]

---

PS: It is not Microsoft related. I did not ever use Windows to develop iOS app.

Comment: why you are using two storyboard with same name?

Comment: I did not . Xcode did it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **Tilde (~)**. 
In Windows file system, The tilde symbol is used to prefix hidden temporary files that are created when a document is opened. For example, when you open a Word document called “Document1.doc,” a file called “~$cument1.doc” is created in the same directory. This file contains information about which user has the file open, to prevent multiple users from attempting to change a document at the same time.

It's nothing but version/copy of your working storyboard file. I never seen copy like this in mac (maybe because they are hidden by defaults), So maybe you copied the code from window or opened once in  window system. or there can be a bug in your version of OS,
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3707538

Anyway nothing to worry and you can delete that file, and check if it created again or not.

Comment: The URI is invalid, please update it.https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3707538